# Is it safe to return a size of a container then changing that container in a finally block?

Tags: java

I'm writing a function that detaches the data from a container and returns the number of elements detached:

```
int detach(foo f)
{
    try {
        /*some code*/
        return m_ids.size();
    } finally {
        m_ids.clear();
    }
}
```

`foo` is an object that receives the data in `m_ids`, which is a `java.util.List`.

My concern: is this code safe? Will it return the size of `m_ids` before it's cleared?

Comment: Wouldn't it have been faster to just try and see? ..then Google " return try finally java" and look for official documentation.?

Comment: Coming from a C background I'm concerned about the "definedness" of such a construct.

Comment: @SnoopDog It is well defined in Java.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The code is safe. The return value is established (and stored somewhere) *before* the `finally` block is reached. Once the `finally` block has ran, the stored return value is sent to the function caller.

Note thought that if you had written, in poor coding style, `return m_ids.size();` as the last statement in the `finally` block then 0 would have been returned to the caller: a `return` value in a `finally` block overrides any other `return` value.

Answer (score 1):

Check the generated bytecode:

```
int detach(java.util.List);
    Code:
       0: aload_1
       1: invokeinterface #4,  1  // InterfaceMethod java/util/List.size:()I
       6: istore_2
       7: aload_1
       8: invokeinterface #5,  1  // InterfaceMethod java/util/List.clear:()V
      13: iload_2
      14: ireturn
      15: astore_3
      16: aload_1
      17: invokeinterface #5,  1  // InterfaceMethod java/util/List.clear:()V
      22: aload_3
      23: athrow
```

`istore_2` is the operation that stores the result of `size` into a local variable, which is then loaded (`iload_2`) and get returned.

Answer (score -5):

Your finally block will never execute if there no exception thrown.

Comment: That's wrong. It will _always_ be executed.

Comment: That is incorrect! (You learn something new every day). Try it yourself.